# TypeError: response.json is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, postgresql

I would like to upload my query result to API with JSON format for my postgresql database.

However I am getting that my json has not been defined:

**TypeError: response.json is not a function**

How to upload this data to the bank?

I would like to upload the data in a conventional way in SQL and not as a JSON field to be able to make queries in the future

**index.js**

```
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
require('isomorphic-fetch');

let content = {

    "query": `{
                squads {
                    name
                        cards(includedOnKanban: true, closed: false, archived: false, cancelled: false, updatedSince: \"2020-01-01T00:00:00-0300\") {
                            identifier
                            title
                            description
                            status
                            priority

                            assignees {
                                fullname
                                email
                              }

                        }
                    }
            }`

};

fetch('https://www.bluesight.io/graphql', {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Bluesight-API-Token': 'token-here'
},
body: JSON.stringify(content)
})
.then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json()
    } else {
      return Promise.reject('something went wrong!')
    }
  })
.then(response => console.log(response.data))
.then(response => console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data)));

const { Client } = require('pg');

const client = new Client({
    user: 'postgres',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    database: 'dbbase',
    password: 'postgres',
    port: 5432,
})
client.connect();
client.query('INSERT INTO tb_bluesight (identifier,title,description,status,priority,fullname,email,date_insert) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, current_timestamp)', response => response.json());
client.end();
```

**JSON**

```
{
    "data": {
        "squads": [
            {
                "name": "SUPPORT IT",
                "cards": [
                    {
                        "identifier": "06x38y",
                        "title": "ALL - Validate data,
                        "description": "review database.",
                        "status": null,
                        "priority": "medium",
                        "assignees": [
                            {
                                "fullname": "Carlos",
                                "email": "carlos@br.it.com",
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE tb_bluesight(
identifier varchar,
title varchar,
description varchar,
status varchar,
priority varchar,
fullname varchar,
email varchar,
date_insert timestamp
);
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that there is actually a response from your server/API and the body contains JSON? Maybe include the controller/endpoint code as well.

Comment: yes, the server is returning the data!

Comment: the problem is in assembling the insert

Comment: Why is the title of the question stating that the response.json() is undefined then? Where is the problem? If you are referring to the DB INSERT statement, where does `response => response.json()` come from? It looks as though you’re expecting data back from the fetch?

Comment: Actually who is returning this value and the insert

Comment: .then(response => console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data)));

Comment: This part returns the data

Comment: It doesn’t look like you’re storing the data fetched from the server outside of the fetch calls?

Comment: could it be, any suggestions?

Comment: you’re not assigning that to anything though. You’re just accessing it and console.log()’ing it. Try ‘const json = fetch(// etc.)’ and you’ll need to use a template literal in your INSERT string

Comment: Could you comment on a piece of code as an answer? Please!

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = fetch('https://www.bluesight.io/graphql', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Bluesight-API-Token': 'token-here'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(content)
})
.then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
        return response.json()
    } else {
        return Promise.reject('something went wrong!')
    }
});

const { Client } = require('pg');

const client = new Client({
    user: 'postgres',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    database: 'dbbase',
    password: 'postgres',
    port: 5432,
});

client.connect();

// Example, replace with real values
const parameters = ['$1', '$2', '$3', '$4','$5', '$6', '$7'];

const query = "INSERT INTO tb_bluesight 
 (identifier,title,description,status,priority,fullname,email,date_insert) 
     VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";

client.query(query, parameters, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err.stack)
    } else {
        // res.rows will contain the inserted rows
        console.log(res.rows[0])
    }
});

client.end();
```

Comment: Error: Connection terminated
    at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:254:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:417:28)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:323:22)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:78:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (net.js:668:12)

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: @LuisHenrique I assume you copied and pasted that? 1. You have not provided a full example. 2. You have not given package/dependency versions etc. The answer I gave is a rudimentary example, the SQL related code was essentially taken from the PG docs. Unless you can provide a proper example and can confirm the exact problem it'll be difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much, but how can I convert parameters for my json?

Comment: @LuisHenrique I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean by "how can I convert parameters for my json"?